# Setting body width not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I'm currently styling a site with CSS and because of the nature of the project, I do not have access to add or remove HTML, just the CSS.

My goal is to simply give the page a fixed width. The HTML of the page is extremely simple and resembles something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    content
  </body>
</html
```

I've attempted to give the body a fixed with via CSS, but IE doesn't appear to respect this property (though other browsers do). Of course, I would much rather throw a DIV in there and give it a width, but the variables are pretty strict on this project.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 0):

If you can only change the CSS and are using IE7 or earlier, than you're SOL, because those browsers don't support the width property on `<body>`.  You probably already checked, but if you haven't, see if there are any existing containing elements you can attach your style to.

If you have a really strict window width (like you always run in full-screen mode), then you maybe using margins will work for you:

```
body {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

Kind of limited, I know.

Answer (score -1):

**Try using jQuery:**

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").css("width",100);

});

</script>

</head>
<body>

x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x


</body>
</html>
```

**Or using CSS like this:**

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script>

<style>

body
{
    width:150;
}

</style>

</head>
<body id="body">

x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x


</body>
</html>
```